# Compositions with first part 1

Tags: combinatorics

How many compositions of n has first part 1?

I've been trying to figure this out, if the number of compositions on n is 2^(n-1) then would the number of compositions of n with the first part 1 be 2^(n-2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fix the first part of your composition of $n$, then the remaining parts give a composition of $n-1$. Therefore the formula you give is basically correct, though you should have some doubt about its validity for $n\leq1$. In fact the number of compositions of $n$ equals $2^{n-1}$ only if $n>0$ (and the number $0$ has one, empty, composition), so the number of composition of $n$ with first part $1$ is $2^{n-2}$ only if $n>1$. The full formula is
$$
  \#\{\text{compositions of $n$ with first part }1\} =
  \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }n=0\\ 1 & \text{if }n=1\\ 2^{n-2} & \text{if }n>1
  \end{cases}
$$

Comment: (+1): What if $n<0$? (Kidding.)

Comment: Thank you!! What if the second part is 1 instead of the first part? Would it still be the same solution?

Comment: @kevlar. Into every non-empty composition of $n-1$ one can insert a part $1$ after the first part, so as to obtain a composition of $n$ with second part $1$. So the answer for this case would be the same as the one for the first part _except_ that that value for $n=1$ would be $0$ (there can be no second part for $n=1$).